# Case insensitive situation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, knockout.js

I have a cshtml page and a select option in that page.

```
<div class="t-input">
                        <select class="tia-input c-combo" data-bind="options: artists,
    optionsText: 'content', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Sanatçı...', value: artist">
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

And I call getArtists js function from my view model to list artists in dropdown menu.

```
self.getArtists = function () {
            webRequest.getSync("/api/Work/GetArtistList", null, self.getArtistsSucceeded);
        }
        self.getArtistsSucceeded = function (result) {
            if (result === null || result.length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var artistModel = new ArtistModel(result[i].stringId, result[i].content);
                self.artists.push(artistModel);
            }
            $(".c-combo").chosen({
                'no_results_text': 'hiçbir sonuç',
                'placeholder_text_single': 'asdasd'
            });
        }
```

Everything is ok. However When I search an artist from menu. I can not find some records. For Example: I have an artist named hisuji and I type HİSUJİ to find him. However He cannot found. When I type HISUJI to find him. He can be found. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Fix that in your API?

Comment: If your search is being done in the API, then you need to fix your API do be case-insensitive.  If your search is being done in your JS code, please provide your search code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this with static data?

I was take same error a while ago, my problem was mysql charset collation, i changed my charset collation utf8_general_ci to utf8_turkish_ci and problem gone..